# Postgres equivalent of MySQL update based on order

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In MySQL it's very easy to update a table over the result of an order by, such as the following:

```
SET @counter=1;
UPDATE task SET priority = (@counter:=@counter+1) ORDER BY createdAt ASC;
```

What would be the equivalent query on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` to a table of row numbers generated with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function (selecting row numbers based on the order of `createdAt`):

```
UPDATE task
SET priority = p.priority
FROM (SELECT createdAt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY createdAt) AS priority
      FROM task) p 
WHERE p.createdAt = task.createdAt
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b1701a8b7f3f8303f80194fc65f24cbb)